Why wasn’t the footage of Peter Parker from the Sam Raimi series shown?
As Miguel O'Hara was teaching Miles Morales about the concept
of a Canon Event, and how it is a constant throughout each universe
within the Spider-Verse, where Miles witness a series of footage where
Peter Parker losing closed relative and first of the series is the Peter Parker
was presented that showed him at the death of Gwen's father George Stacy, and how his
death is a Canon Event:

I believe the first of the series should be Peter Parker from the Sam Raimi series,
as it was the first live-action Spider-Man movie
Why wasn’t the footage of Peter Parker from the Sam Raimi series shown?

Sam Raimi film was represented https://intothespiderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Cliff_Robertson

Then why not here?

Almost certainly because cartoon Gwen is also there and the live version is related to her too.
